# criação de menu CSS

Tags: html, css, menu

Olá,

gostaria de sabe qual a forma mais facil de criar um menu em HTML pelo CSS? Tentei fazer um aqui e realmente não deu certo.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="pt-br">


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clube Front-end!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"


</head>

<body>
    <header>
            <h1><img  src="img/logo.png"></h1>

            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=index.html>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="equipe">Equipe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contato">Contato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="discord">Nosso Dicord</a></li>




                </ul>
            </nav>


            <h2>Clube Front-end é um site de cunho estudantil para unir pessoas que desenvolvem WEB seja como hobbie ou profissional! faça parte de nossa equipe e una-se a essa comunidade!</h2>
    </header>

    <div>

    <p>Bem vindo amigos, hoje vou escrever um pouco da minha aventura como desenvolvedor de WEB, hoje já faz uma semana que adiquiri um curso na <em>Udemy</em>, um grande curso desenvolvido pelo professor <i>André Fontenelle</i> que é um instrutor excelente.</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

e  meu CSS assim ...

```
    body {
            background: black;
            font-family: cursive,sans-serif;
            color: white;

        }

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    }

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    }


title {
    text-align: center
    }

#menu ul li a {

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    }

#menu ul li { display: inline; }

#menu ul li a {
    padding: 2px 10px;
    display: inline-block;

    /* visual do link */
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EDEDED


}

#menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #D6D6D6;
    color: #6D6D6D;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EA0000
}
```

Comment: Cara como assim não deu? Asua tag `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"` está faltando um ">" no final. Tirando isso já aparece um menu na página... O que mais exatamente vc precisa?

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, estou começando no mundo de desenvolvimento de web. Consegui resolver meu problema com sua ajuda, só faltou realmente fechar a tag.

Comment: Vou te dar uma dica. Utiliza algum editor de código que te mostre esse tipo de erro. Foi só eu color o seu código no meu editor o VS Code que na hora eu vi que tinha uma tag aberta.... Sempre tenha atenção aos detalhos, boa sorte ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Vou responder aqui o que respondi no comentário apenas para vc poder marcar a pergunta como resolvida e ela não ficar em aberto no site voltando para lista de **perguntas não respondidas** ok.*

A sua tag `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"` está aberta, no final dela está faltando um  <kbd>></kbd>  no final.

Aproveito para te dar uma dica. Utiliza algum editor de código que te mostre esse tipo de erro. Foi só eu colocar o seu código no meu editor *(eu uso o VS Code)* que na hora eu vi que tinha uma tag aberta.

*Código funcionando abaixo*

```css
 body {
            background: black;
            font-family: cursive,sans-serif;
            color: white;

        }

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    }

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    }


title {
    text-align: center
    }

#menu ul li a {

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    }

#menu ul li { display: inline; }

#menu ul li a {
    padding: 2px 10px;
    display: inline-block;

    /* visual do link */
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EDEDED


}

#menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #D6D6D6;
    color: #6D6D6D;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #EA0000
}
```

```html
<header>
            <h1><img  src="img/logo.png"></h1>

            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=index.html>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="equipe">Equipe</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contato">Contato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="discord">Nosso Dicord</a></li>




                </ul>
            </nav>


            <h2>Clube Front-end é um site de cunho estudantil para unir pessoas que desenvolvem WEB seja como hobbie ou profissional! faça parte de nossa equipe e una-se a essa comunidade!</h2>
    </header>

    <div>

    <p>Bem vindo amigos, hoje vou escrever um pouco da minha aventura como desenvolvedor de WEB, hoje já faz uma semana que adiquiri um curso na <em>Udemy</em>, um grande curso desenvolvido pelo professor <i>André Fontenelle</i> que é um instrutor excelente.</p>
    </div>
```